# WaitForSeconds Error in Unity5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to set up a simple script where if I collide with an object (just a simple box for now) then it triggers text to show on the screen with the "zone" name.

I'm getting a script error and I can't seem to figure out what it's telling me to do.  I've tried to look at various tutorials but what keeps coming up is something static like a player name or score.

I want the text to fade after a bit, hence the extra function at the end that I am trying to pass the zone name to.  I am attaching this script to each zone trigger.

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ZoneAnnounce : MonoBehaviour {

    // Text Object
    private Text zoneNameText;

    // Exposed Text Variable
    public string zoneName = "Unknown";

    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col) {

        if ( col.gameObject.name == "Player" ) {
            StartCoroutine(showZoneInfo(zoneName));
        }

    }   

    IEnumerator showZoneInfo (string zoneName) {

        zoneNameText.text = zoneName;

        yield return WaitForSeconds(3);

    }

}
```

and here's the error I am getting:

> Assets/ZoneAnnounce.cs(26,16): error CS0119: Expression denotes a type, where a variable, value or method group was expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here: `yield return WaitForSeconds(3);`

`WaitForSeconds` is `class`. To yield it you have to create new instance of it. This can be done by simply adding the `new` keyword before `WaitForSeconds`.

Change that to `yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);`

---

If you already know the time(3 seconds) to wait, you can create new instance of `WaitForSeconds` then use it without the new keyword.

```
WaitForSeconds waitTime = new WaitForSeconds(3);
IEnumerator showZoneInfo(string zoneName)
{

    zoneNameText.text = zoneName;
    yield return waitTime;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding.  Thank you.